# Printer not visible over network between 12.04 machines, Printer properties reports "Not published. See server settings"

Tags: networking, printing, sharing

I'm attempting to share a USB attached printer connected to one 12.04 machine to another 12.04 machine (and a 10.04 machine) on the same network.  The printer does not show up and cannot be found as a network printer by the second machine.

On the first machine, I have "Shared" , "Enabled", and "Accepting Jobs" selected in Printer Properties, with "Access Control" set to Allow printing for everyone and a right click on the printer has "Shared" selected.

However printer properties shows a message "Not published.  See server settings.".  I don't know what settings it is referring to.

Note if relevant the print server in this case was installed as a 12.04 Beta and then upgraded when 12.04 was released.

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the top menu bar, there is a dropdown menu for "Server" in order to enable the print server.

This got me too.

Comment: PS: You have to minimize any full screen windows to see the bar with the Server Menu!

Comment: What "top menu bar", what "dropdown menu" for "Server"? Can't find this anywhere on 14.04